# Consider the function $ f: [-1,1] \rightarrow [-1,1] $ defined by $ \ f(x)=\frac{3}{2}x^2-1 $.

Tags: polynomials, roots

Consider the function $ f: [-1,1] \rightarrow [-1,1] $ defined by $ \ f(x)=\frac{3}{2}x^2-1 $.

Find the fixed points and check their stablity.

**Answer:**

The fixed points are obtained by

$ f(x)=x $,

or, $ \frac{3}{2}x^2-1 =x $

or, $ 3x^2-2x-2=0 $

or, $ x=\frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4+24}}{6}$,

or, $ x= \frac{1}{3} [1 \pm \sqrt{7} ]$

or, $ x=-0.54$ and $x=1.21 $

But $ x=-0.54 \in [-1,1 ]$ only.

So there is only one fixed point.

Now, $ f'(-0.54) =3 (-0.54)  <0 $.

So $ x=\frac{1}{3}(1 -\sqrt 7)$ is stable.

**I need confirmation of my work . Any help ?**

Comment: The computations are correct.

Comment: should'nt you check $|f'|<1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed point is not stable, the function does not satisfy the Lipschitz condition on the given interval. Indeed

$f'(x)=3x$ and $|f'(x)|<1$ is false on the given interval $[-1,1]$

For the fixed point theorem, starting with $x_0=-0.5$ and applying iteratively $f(x)$ the sequence should converge, but this doesn't

$$\{-0.5,-0.625,-0.414,-0.742,-0.172,-0.955,0.369,-0.795,-0.051,\ldots\}$$
are the first values, which show that the sequence does not converge